# Insert data from one table to another where one column matches in both efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables, "BLANKTABLE" and "ACTIVETABLE". They have the same columns "Company, City, State". Active table has millions of records in each column, BLANK table only has the "Company" column filled out (other columns empty). There is a big over lap between the two.

I want to insert the row data (city and state) from ACTIVETABLE into BLANKTABLE where the Company field matches on both. So if both tables had the company "Example" in the company column, it would insert the city and state data from ACTIVE into BLANK basically cloning that row from ACTIVE. My first thought is this, but I have a feeling it's incredibly inefficient.

```
INSERT INTO BLANKTABLE
  (Company, [City], [State])
SELECT de.company,
       de.[city],
       de.[state]
  FROM [ACTIVETABLE] de
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT website, company, zip
                    FROM BLANKTABLE d2
                   WHERE d2.company = de.company)
```

Any thoughts?

UPDATE:

Actually, maybe this is the way

```
UPDATE blanktable
SET    blanktable.city = activetable.city,
       blanktable.state = activetable.state
FROM   blanktable d2
       INNER JOIN activetable de
               ON d2.company = de.company;
```

Right?

Comment: If you want to insert new rows, use the first method.  If you want to update existing rows, use the second.  I'm not clear what your question is.

Comment: I wanted to update the rows, not insert new ones. I realize now how dumb that first query is! Thank you

Comment: Edit yuor question, is very confuse what do you want, update or insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like there are multiple ActiveTable rows for any Company and you want to **summarize** by company and then update BlankTable (and possibly add to BlankTable if you find companies in ActiveTable that are in BlankTable).

I think this whole process would be a bit clearer for you if you used a Merge statement instead of an Update or an Insert.  [You can read about the syntax here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Basically the important thing here is to design a query against ActiveTable that returns one row per company with the particular values of city & state that you want to have in BlankTable.  I'd recommend using the most recent ActiveTable value if you have the data there that allows you to distinguish that.  You can fill in the blanks, but the basic syntax is:

```
Merge into Blanktable b
Using (Select <company city state values> From activeTable Group By company) a
On B.company = A.company
When Matched Then Update Set b.city = a.city, b.state=a.state
When Not Matched Then Insert (company,city,state) Values (a.company, a.city, a.state)
```

This full syntax Updates if the company is present in BlankTable and Inserts if it's not there. If you don't want to add records to BlankTable, just update the existing ones, then omit the When Not Matched section.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer to your question. Your update query should work just fine.